# NEON acceleration for 12-bit to 8-bit

Tags: image-processing, compiler-optimization, neon

I have a buffer of 12-bit data (stored in 16-bit data)
and need to converts into 8-bit (shift by 4)

How can the NEON accelerate this processing ?

Thank you for your help

Brahim

Comment: It's a little tricky but it can be done - what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 3):

Took the liberty to assume a few things explained below, but this kind of code (untested, may require a few modifications) should provide a good speedup compared to naive non-NEON version:

```
#include <arm_neon.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void convert(const restrict *uint16_t input, // the buffer to convert
             restrict *uint8_t output,       // the buffer in which to store result
             int sz) {                       // their (common) size

  /* Assuming the buffer size is a multiple of 8 */
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i += 8) {
    // Load a vector of 8 16-bit values:
    uint16x8_t v = vld1q_u16(buf+i);
    // Shift it by 4 to the right, narrowing it to 8 bit values.
    uint8x8_t shifted = vshrn_n_u16(v, 4);
    // Store it in output buffer
    vst1_u8(output+i, shifted);
  }

}
```

Things I assumed here:

- that you're working with unsigned values. If it's not the case, it will be easy to adapt anyway (`uint*` -> `int*`, `*_u8`->`*_s8` and `*_u16`->`*_s16`)
- as the values are loaded 8 by 8, I assumed the buffer length was a multiple of 8 to avoid edge cases. If that's not the case, you should probably pad it artificially to a multiple of 8.

Finally, the 2 resource pages used from the NEON documentation:

- about [loads and stores](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0348c/BABDCGGF.html) of vectors.
- about [shifting vectors](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0348c/BABIBBJG.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: you don't need the q flag to be set unless you also set the r flag. nothing to saturate here.

Comment: True, that's a bad copy-paste from the NEON documentation! Fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. I will do some tests. I am trying to include such code into a Qt 4.8 application, and need to remove the "const restrict". The buf+i was changed to input+i. Data is 12-bit unsigned into 16-bit and now shifted into 8-bit unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

```
prototype : void dataConvert(void * pDst, void * pSrc, unsigned int count);
    1:
    vld1.16 {q8-q9}, [r1]!
    vld1.16 {q10-q11}, [r1]!
    vqrshrn.u16 d16, q8, #4
    vqrshrn.u16 d17, q9, #4
    vqrshrn.u16 d18, q10, #4
    vqrshrn.u16 d19, q11, #4
    vst1.16 {q8-q9}, [r0]!
    subs r2, #32
    bgt 1b
```

q flag : saturation

r flag : rounding

change u16 to s16 in case of signed data.